# Oracle identity column and insert into select

Tags: oracle, identity-column, oracle12c

Oracle 12 introduced nice feature (which should have been there long ago btw!) - identity columns. So here's a script:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    a INTEGER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    b VARCHAR2(10)
);

-- Ok
INSERT INTO test (b) VALUES ('x');

-- Ok
INSERT INTO test (b)
SELECT 'y' FROM dual;

-- Fails
INSERT INTO test (b)
SELECT 'z' FROM dual UNION ALL SELECT 'zz' FROM DUAL;
```

First two inserts run without issues providing values for 'a' of 1 and 2. But the third one fails with `ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("DEV"."TEST"."A")`. Why did this happen? A bug? Nothing like this is mentioned in the documentation part about [identity column restrictions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/server.121/e17209/statements_7002.htm#SQLRF55661). Or am I just doing something wrong?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I believe the below query works, i havent tested!

```
INSERT INTO Test (b)
SELECT * FROM
(
   SELECT 'z' FROM dual
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 'zz' FROM dual
);
```

Not sure, if it helps you any way.

For, `GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY` Oracle internally uses a Sequence only. And the options on general Sequence applies on this as well.

NEXTVAL is used to fetch the next available sequence, and obviously it is a pseudocolumn.

The below is from [Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/server.121/e17209/pseudocolumns002.htm)

You cannot use `CURRVAL` and `NEXTVAL` in the following constructs:

- A subquery in a `DELETE`, `SELECT`, or `UPDATE` statement
- A query of a view or of a materialized view
- A SELECT statement with the DISTINCT operator
- A SELECT statement with a GROUP BY clause or ORDER BY clause
- A `SELECT` statement that is combined with another `SELECT` statement with the UNION, `INTERSECT`, or `MINUS` set operator
- The WHERE clause of a SELECT statement
- DEFAULT value of a column in a CREATE TABLE or ALTER TABLE statement
- The condition of a CHECK constraint

The `subquery` and `SET` operations rule above should answer your Question.

And for the reason for NULL, when `pseudocolumn`(eg. NEXTVAL) is used with a SET operation or any other rules mentioned above, the output is NULL, as Oracle couldnt extract them in effect with combining multiple selects.

Let us see the below query,

```
select rownum from dual
union all 
select rownum from dual
```

the result is

```
ROWNUM
1
1
```

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation! In fact, when using sequence explicitly, `INSERT INTO test (a) SELECT seq.nextval FROM dual UNION ALL SELECT seq.nextval FROM dual;` brings more explanatory `"ORA-02287: sequence number not allowed here"`. It seems that identity column must bypass this check somehow, but the sequence does not work anyway, providing just NULL as the value - hence the unusual error message.

Comment: I don't have enough rep to edit, but the last bullet should be 3 separate bullets. It's hard to read as-is.