# Strange Behaviour Related to ORA-01400 Error

Tags: oracle, sql-insert, oracle12c, ora-01400

I'm creating a table on our database with version `Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64b`

```
create table tahakkuk_kalem(
                           id       int generated always as identity primary key,       
                           aciklama varchar2(250),
                           tur      int default 0 not null 
                          );
```

and then applying some insert statements :

```
SQL> insert into tahakkuk_kalem(aciklama) select 'Atıksu' from dual;

SQL> select * from tahakkuk_kalem;

ID  ACIKLAMA  TUR
--  --------  --- 
1   Atıksu     0

SQL> rollback;

SQL> insert into tahakkuk_kalem(aciklama,tur) select 'Atıksu',0 from dual;

ID  ACIKLAMA  TUR
--  --------  --- 
2   Atıksu     0

SQL> rollback;
```

So far so good, but if I issue the statement below ;

```
SQL> insert into tahakkuk_kalem(aciklama,tur) 
     select 'Atıksu',0 from dual union all select 'Ceza',0 from dual;
```

met an incomprehensible error statement :

> **ORA-01400:** cannot insert NULL into ("MY_SCHEMA"."TAHAKKUK_KALEM"."ID")

Do you have any opinion what could be the reason ?

Comment: I replicated this in a Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 environment and in a Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 environment. 12.2 works just fine, while 12.1 threw the error mentioned from you. Maybe there is a problem with 12.1 version.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Oracle identity column and insert into select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21355770/oracle-identity-column-and-insert-into-select)

Comment: thank you very much @AlessandroMelo that answers. Very interesting.

Comment: yes, that should be a bug, thanks @ErgiNushi .